# Space-saving plotting technique

Tags: tables, pgfplots, charts

My goal is to create a template for a report (see the figure) that will be used to programmatically generate reports from a data source. The approach I have thought of is to use a table combined with pgfplots to obtain the desired appearance. Note that there should be no waste of space, i.e. spacing between the plots is unacceptable. Another thing worth mentioning is that the horizontal lines marking the depth has to align perfectly across the whole page

What would be the best approach to achieve the desired results?

Comments and directions are highly appreciated.

[image: Part of the report that has to be generated.]

Comment: just rotate plots inside a tabular ?

Comment: @percusse, could you provide a MWE? I have tried what you suggest, but I cannot figure out how to get rid of the space between the plots. Another thing worth mentioning is that the horizontal lines marking the depth has to align perfectly across the whole page.

Comment: Well these are all extra specs now don't you think? Please add all of them at once to your question

Comment: Question is updated now.

Comment: You can get some way along at least with a `groupplot` (see `pgfplots` manual, chapter 5.8 *Grouping plots*). Set `horizontal sep=0pt` and set `ymin`, `ymax` and any grid/ytick settings in the options for the `groupplot` environment`

Comment: For this type of complex graphic confection, I've had good results using python or perl to generate Metapost source (or even raw PostScript).

Comment: You might also look at R with Lattice graphics or ggplot2.